# typescript mapDispatchToProps got error when import component require pass actions as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm new to redux and try to use it with Typescript.

I use `mapDispatchProps` for `connect()` in the component, when import this component, it requires to pass actions as props which it shouldn't.
The weird thing is when I tried with other actions, it seems fine, but just something wrong with this one.

The full code is 
[here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/relaxed-sunset-tqnb1)
and the error message in `index.tsx`, where I want to import component.

Error message

> Property 'getInputUserName' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly>'.ts(2741)
>   App.tsx(8, 3): 'getInputUserName' is declared here.

Really happy to hear any advice.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the action with same name as it is declared in the `Props` interface.

So either try this -

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getInputUserName: loginUserName }
)(App)
```

or this -

```
interface Props {
  inputUserName: string;
  loginUserName: typeof loginUserName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getInputUserName: loginUserName }
)(App);
```

Cheers,